# Include an App like a browser, in a .jar?

Tags: java, jar, portable-applications

I wrote a simple socket in java, with netbeans, that listens for connections and that can perform other simple actions.

The problem is that, i have to force users of my app, to **use a specific browser** (i.e. firefox). How i can achive this?

It's a good idea attach it (**in a portable version**) to my .jar? If yes, how i can do this?
Exist some other way to do it?

I'm not very expert in Java, so any idea or any help is appreciated :)
Thanks.

Comment: Considering multiple platform dependencies and the fact you can install Firefox pretty much anywhere and with any given user, you're likely out of luck. You probably want to explicitly inform your users that your application only supports Firefox instead.

Comment: @Mena i need it only for windows system, and i cant be sure that some user are able to install it alone (cause no internet, no knowledge or other motivation)...

Comment: What about using the limited HTML capabilities of java, write a mini-browser?

Comment: @JoopEggen With java-fx the HTML capabilities became pretty good, see my post. Last time I used the webkit view it was like a Chrome 17 or 18

Comment: @ChristianKuetbach yes, JavaFX is beautiful, though swing can do with some effort. I am not sure about https though.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you *can* (legally and otherwise) bundle Firefox to your application (and I still recommend otherwise), here's a minimal example of how to use a process in java, to run Firefox parametrized with a given URL.

```
// this is Linux-ish - adapt accordingly
String myBundledFirefox = "/usr/bin/firefox";
String myAppURL = "http://stackoverflow.com"; 
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(myBundledFirefox, myAppURL);
pb.start();
```

This may (or may not) run Firefox in your machine and open the SO page, given a relatively broad list of circumstances.

Take a look at the [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html), to set your expectations straight about this.

In particular, the [start](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#start%28%29) method lists a number of exceptional conditions, the most relevant of which listed here (quoting the docs):

- > [SecurityException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/SecurityException.html) - if a security manager exists and its 
  >   checkExec method doesn't allow creation of the subprocess, or the standard input to the subprocess was redirected from a file and the security manager's checkRead method denies read access to the file, or the standard output or standard error of the subprocess was redirected to a file and the security manager's checkWrite method denies write access to the file
- > [IOException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/IOException.html) - if an I/O error occurs

Answer (score 0):

Enforcing a special browser is a bad habit.

I would suggest to rewrite some portions of your code to make it X-browser compatible.

If you have done this, you could use [java-FX and create a webkit based browser](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/webview/jfxpub-webview.htm) instance, without using any system dependencies.

Comment: It does not depend on my app, it is a part of more big application, so i need to adapt to it... :)

Thanks for suggestion anyway!